# Unexpected printing inside and outside during multiprocessing

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing

I have 3 Python files -
1] test file - which executes the main do_add function - a very small program with a delay.

```
print('Before entering name==main')
if __name__=="__main__":
   from library.poc.name_main.name_main_2 import do_operate1
   print('Condition satisfied.')
   x = [9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2]
   y = [10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3]
   result = do_operate1(x,y)
   print('result of do add on',x,'and',y,':',result, 'validate', sum(x) + sum(y))
else:
   print('No condition satisfied.',__name__)
```

2] do_operate file , which has a function, which processes two list of numbers

```
def do_operate1(x_list,y_list):
   tuple_value_list = []
   # for i,j in it.chain(range(1,x+1), range(1,y+1)):
   for i, j in zip(x_list,y_list):
       tuple_value = (i,j)
       # print(i,j)
       tuple_value_list.append(tuple_value)
   if len(x_list) < 7:
       cpu_count = len(x_list)
   elif len(x_list) >= 7:
       cpu_count = 7
   pool = multiprocessing.Pool(cpu_count)
   sum_val = 0
   for result in pool.starmap(do_add, tuple_value_list):
       sum_val = sum_val + result
   pool.close()
   return sum_val
```

3] d0_add , which adds 2 numbers after sleeping for the duration of the sum of two numbers.

```
import time
# main function
def do_add(x,y):
   time.sleep(x+y)
   print('Input x',x,'and y',y,'result', x+y)
   return x + y
```

When executing , I am getting the result but certain lines are getting printed , which were not expected. What could be wrong.

```
Before entering name==main
Condition satisfied.
Before entering name==main
No condition satisfied. __mp_main__
Before entering name==main
No condition satisfied. __mp_main__
Before entering name==main
No condition satisfied. __mp_main__
Before entering name==main
No condition satisfied. __mp_main__
Before entering name==main
No condition satisfied. __mp_main__
Before entering name==main
No condition satisfied. __mp_main__
Before entering name==main
No condition satisfied. __mp_main__
Input x 3 and y 4 result 7
Input x 4 and y 5 result 9
Input x 5 and y 6 result 11
Input x 2 and y 3 result 5
Input x 6 and y 7 result 13
Input x 7 and y 8 result 15
Input x 8 and y 9 result 17
Input x 9 and y 10 result 19
result of do add on [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2] and [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3] : 96 validate 96
```

Below are my queries.
1] Since the condition is satisfied for the first time, the line “Before entering name==main” should not be printed more than once
2] Why is the statement - “No condition satisfied. **mp_main**” getting printed multiple times
3] Where am I going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Imports should be done before `if __name__ == "__main__":` line, and all functions should be "importable" if they are to work in a multiprocess program.

The way this works is that each worker will spawn a new interpreter and it will import your main file in order to find the function to execute, it won't find the function because it is not readable by anyone importing the script, then the worker crash and exit, then your main process is going to run that function as a last resort after all the workers fail.

**Edit:** to clarify this even more, each of the 7 children processes start with something like.

```py
__name__ = "__mp_main__"
import main_script
main_script.execute_the_work()
```

this is what triggers the extra printing.

Comment: I had tried doing the import before if __name__ == "__main__" but the output remains the same

Comment: @PremJi the child processes **will** import your main file, there is nothing you can do about it, except removing the `print('No condition satisfied.',__name__)` line and `print('Before entering name==main')` line ... this is not a "bug" to fix, it's simply how multiprocessing works, there are ways to prevent this, but this is not your case, and preventing it is sometimes messy and has substantial overhead.

Comment: Thanks @Ahmed AEK for your time to look into this. Is there any way to control the child process importing the main file.

Comment: @PremJi consider the following, if it didn't import your main, it won't find the function to execute, so it will be told to execute a function which it knows nothing about ... so it will crash, this is how multiprocessing is implemented in python, now there is `loky` module that pickles functions by value to avoid this but it has higher overhead compared to python's multiprocessing module. and some limitations so don't use it for "convenience" it's only there when it is necessary.

Comment: @PremJi consider in the above example you remove the `import main_script`, the next line `main_script.execute_the_work()` will result in a name error ... see why it has to import the main script ?